# Rotate custom shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

Below code create a custom shape 'N'. It works fine with 0 rotation,but if rotate 90 degree, it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    cap/.style={
        rotate=#1,very thick,rectangle,minimum width=2mm,minimum height=4mm,
        inner sep=0,outer sep=0,
        path picture={
            \draw(path picture bounding box.south west) -- 
            (path picture bounding box.north west)
            (path picture bounding box.south east) -- 
            (path picture bounding box.north east)
            (path picture bounding box.north east) -- (path picture bounding box.south west);
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[cap=0] (C1) {};
    \node[cap=45,below=0.2 of C1] (C2) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this example, C1 is good. C2 is the rotated version:

[image]

Two issues:

1. The line width not the same, the middle line looks like more wider.
2. The rotation function doesn't work.

Comment: One good example to create custom shape https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=38jy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `path picture`s are not without subtleties. For this purpose I would, rather than playing with `\pgftransformreset` and the like, argue that `pic`s may be more straightforward to deal with. Using `local bounding box`es one can make them almost behave like nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    pics/.cd,
     N/.style={code={\draw[very thick] (-0.1,0.2) -- (-0.1,-0.2) 
     -- (0.1,0.2) -- (0.1,-0.2);
     }}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[local bounding box=C1] {N};
    \pic[local bounding box=C2,rotate=45,below=0.4 of C1] {N};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

your expectation how `path picture bounding box` is wrong. in your case instead it you can use `append after command` and add your drawings as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    cap/.style={
        rotate=#1,very thick,rectangle, minimum width=2mm,minimum height=4mm,
        inner sep=0,outer sep=0,
        append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
            \draw   (\LN.south west) -- (\LN.north west) --
                    (\LN.south east) -- (\LN.north east);
                        }
                            },
                }% end of cap style
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[cap=0] (C1) {};
    \node[cap=45,below=0.2 of C1] (C2) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, but sounds like the rotate is not around center. if rotate  C2 with 90 degree, you will find it's not center aligned with C1.

Comment: @lucky1928  The pgfmanual says on p. 162 : "Note that this operation should only be used by real experts and should only be used deep inside clever macros, not on normal paths." I have made too many experiences that suggest that this is to be taken seriously. (You can use `\pgfextra` for `\typeouts` and the like without problems, though, according to what I find, but if you use it for paths the outcome is sometimes unpredictable, meaning it can depend on what you've done earlier.)

Comment: @lucky1928, indeed. you should stick with nice marmot answer.